# Jquery tabs: click-event-handler not working when button placed as part of div placed in jquery tab panel

Tags: jquery, tabs, click, eventtrigger

I have button-clicks which do not trigger when placed inside a div in a 'jquery tab' panel. It seems that the 'click' event does not propagate upward in the DOM. Looking for any solution that fix the issue.

```
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zu868twm/5/

**HTML**
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>    <div id="tabs-1">
<div class="div-first" >Content for Tab 1</div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<div>Content for Tab 2</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="tabid">Message:</div>


** JScript **
$(document).bind( 'ready', function(){

jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
          var active = jQuery('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
              //Populate #tab-1 with submit button

       str1 = '<div class="span_spe"><button class="rdbox1 error   
         req_homepage check_spe" name="req_s" >TabDivButton</button></div>';

                //content only for #tab-1 for this example

        $('#tabs-1 .div-first').show();
                $('#tabs-1 .div-first').html('');
      $('#tabs-1 .div-first').html(str1);

   }
    });
});

 //Click 'Tab 2' and then 'Tab 1' manually to see the button first.
//Main issue: this trigger handler not working on button click.

jQuery('#tabs-1 .div-first button').click(function() {
    jQuery("#tabid").html('I am in submit button of tab');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to use jQuery's [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) on an element that doesn't exist yet. You are injecting the button dynamically, so you'll have to use a delegate instead of bind. Also, [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the preferred method for attaching event handlers:

```
$('#tabs-1').on('click', '.div-first button', function() {
    $("#tabid").html('I am in submit button of tab');
});
```